# Recursion in template part of Vue component?

Tags: javascript, recursion, vue.js

I have this data set in the form of:

```
[{
  id: docID - 1,
  name: "Root Element - 1",
  parent: null
},
 {
   id: docID - 2,
   name: "Child Item - 1",
   parent: docID - 1
 }, {
   id: docID - 3,
   name: "Child Item - 2",
   parent: "docID - 2"
 }, {
   id: docID - 4,
   name: "Root Element - 2",
   parent: null
 }]
```

and I want to render it as a tree menu like :

```
Root Element - 1
----------------Child Item - 1
-------------------------------Child Item - 2
Root Element - 2
```

I can `console.log` it using something like:

```
/* where parent === null */
let rootElements = getRootElements(); 

rootElements.forEach(rootElement => {

    console.log(rootElement.name);

    printChildItems(rootElement.id);

});

function printChildElements(parentID) {

    /* where parent === parentID */
    let childElements = getAllChildElements(parentID);

    if(chilElements === null)
        return;


    childElements.forEach(childElement => {
        console.log(childElement);

        /* recursive traversing */
        printChildElements(childElements.id);
    })

};
```

But how to do recursion in template part of `Vue` component?

```
<div v-for="rootCategory in rootCategories" :key="rootCategory.id">
<p> {{ rootCategory.name }} </p> 

<!-- child element loop -->
<div v-for="childElement in getChildElements(rootCategory.id)" :key="childElement.id">
<p class="child"> {{ childElement.name }} </p>

<!-- how to take back the loop control from here,
 back to top of childElement loop to traverse recursively -->

</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Use a [recursive component](https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2017/10/23/vue-js-tree-menu-recursive-components/).